# GNU Parallel with sed wrong arguement as file

Tags: bash, sed, xargs, gnu-parallel

I want to change all occurrences of `<ga/` to `<`. With xargs, this works fine:

```
ls | xargs sed -i 's/<ga\//</g'
```

GNU Parallel says that it's a direct replacement for xargs, but doing

```
ls | parallel sed -i 's/<ga\//</g'
```

results in

```
/bin/bash: ga//: No such file or directory
```

for each file in the directory. I'm sure that I'm just forgetting a {} or \; somewhere, but the answer still alludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls | parallel -q sed -i 's/<ga\//</g'
```